# Enable toolbar in new popup window IE

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, toolbar, bho

How to enable toolbar in new popup window where the toolbar is disabled.
I mean if the window is created using window.open("","toolbar=no") then that window don't have toolbar enabled.
I want to enable toolbar in that.
Is there any way to programmatically/manually achieve that

Comment: Open a new window, close the original.

Comment: I guess you dint got my question at all

Comment: There is no way to add toolbars, that is your option.

Comment: There always is a way to do something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this would do the trick.But I dont know why this code dint show up in any forum.
It is so simple all you have to do is find all the `InternetExplorer` instance and set the `Toolbar` flag to true

```
internal static void enableToolbar()
    {
        ShellWindows shellWindows = new ShellWindows();
        foreach (InternetExplorer ie in shellWindows)
        {
            String filename = ie.Name;
            if (filename.Contains("Internet Explorer"))
            {
                ie.ToolBar = 1;
            }
        }
    }
```